# Analogue of \proofname but for the word "Theorem"

Tags: babel, amsthm, locale

Let's say I'm writing a macro which defines a proof-like environment for beamer. then I can use `\proofname` inside the definition, and the macro works fine with the default ("english") preamble, as well as when I add say `\usepackage[german]{babel}` to the preamble. In the ouput `\proofname` will be replaces by "Proof" when the default preamble is used, and by "Beweis" when babel is loaded.

Now I would like to define a Theorem-like environment. It should be just a box with the word Theorem on top. I have no need for numbering or anything else, but the word "Theorem" should appear in the correct language, as chosen by the babel invocation.

Question: is there an analogue for the word "Theorem/Satz/etc." which works like \proofname works for "proof/Beweis/etc."?

Comment: Please always include a short, but compilable test document in your questions.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `\usepackage[german]{babel}` unless you really want the pre-1995 grammar and spelling rules. If you don't, do please use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: Is something stopping you from writing `\newtheorem{theorem}{Satz}` in the preamble?

Comment: @Mico, yes, but it's irrelevant. If you prefer, we can pretend that I want to write a macro \myfancyreferencingcommand which should print "Theorem 1.2" or "Satz 1.2" etc. depending on how babel was invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Beamer internally uses the `translator` package to translate the names of theorems etc.

You can also use it for defining your own theorems:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usepackage{babel}

\deftranslation[to=French]{Foo}{nom français pour foo}
\deftranslation[to=German]{Foo}{Deutscher Name für Foo}
\newtheorem{foo}{\translate{Foo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}
  content...
  \end{theorem}
  
  \begin{proof}
  content...
  \end{proof}

  \begin{foo}
  content...
  \end{foo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answers my question (neither does the link you provided in your comment) - the point is that in my macro definition I do not want to use my knowledge that the current document is in german. The macro should work correctly also for users of, say, french. To exemplify,  \proofname prints "Beweis", I don't need to write, say \proofname{language="ngerman"}

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski The translator package comes with translations of many commonly used terms in several languages.

Comment: I'm sure it does, the question is how can I use it in a macro definition, specifically for the language which the user chose via babel invocation?

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski You use `\translate{...}` in your macro definition, just like I showed in the newtheorem

Comment: \translate{Theorem} prints Theorem, in a document which has \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} in the preamble.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski use `ngerman` as class option and not as babel option, this way it will reach all packages and not just babel. This way it should print "Satz"

Comment: Is this a  beamer specific solution?  How would I use this solution in, say, report class?

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski You can use it in all classes (but you will have to load the translator package manually)

Comment: in my document I have \documentclass[ngerman]{report}, \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}, \usepackage{translator} and \translate{Theorem} still prints Theorem

Comment: @ŁukaszGrabowski `\documentclass[ngerman]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usedictionary{translator-theorem-dictionary}

\begin{document}
\translate{theorem}
\end{document}
`

Comment: Great thanks, this worked. If you could change your answer to this example then I'll accept it

Comment: Your question explicitly asks about a proof-like environment for beamer, showing a report class answer wouldn't match the question.

Comment: No, that's an example, the question is at the bottom, and it doesn't have anything to do specifically with beamer, it asks for an analogue of the command \proofname for words other than "Proof"